# Не определённая ширина блока слайдера

Tags: javascript, css3, vue.js, slider, swiper

Использую [сладйер swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/). Столкнулся с следующий проблемой: заданное количество слайдов (четыре), не получается разместить по ширине блока который находится выше.Что только не пробывал не помогает.
Стоит уточнить что там будет не четыре блока, а гораздо большое, и при клике на стрелки управления они прокручиваются на один вперед.

**Пример(как должно быть):** [image: пример]

**Как получается**[image: пример2]

Обрезается часть первого слайда, получается они все немного смещены влево

Думаю проблема заключается в отступах между слайдами, если их убрать все нормально.

```js
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    swiperSlides: [
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
    ],
    swiperOption: {
      initialSlide: 0,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    swiper() {
      return this.$refs.mySwiper.swiper;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // current swiper instance
  },
  methods: {
    callback() {
      //read the API docs to see which slider events are available
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-awesome-swiper@3.1.2/dist/vue-awesome-swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>

    <div>
      <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper" @someSwiperEvent="callback">
        <!-- slides -->
        <swiper-slide v-for="(slide, index) in swiperSlides" :key="index">
          <div class="square">
            img
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
      </swiper>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что каждый слайд при инициализации слайдера получает ширину в зависимости от количества видимых слайдов (`slidesPerView`) и ширины блока-родителя слайдера.

Причины, описанного вами, поведения состоят в следующем:

1. Не определена ширина контейнера блока (исправлено: ширина установлена в 600px);
2. Блоку с классом `.square` вы явно задали ширину как `100px`, в то время как при 4 слайдах, каждый слайд получает `600px/4=150px`, что и вызвало `50px` пустого неокрашенного пространства, что создало иллюзию незаполненности (исправлено: удалена ширина `.square` и он принимает `100%` ширины слайда);

Применение в коде `js`: `slidesPerView:4` в примере 1 и `slidesPerView:6` в примере 2, а также `spaceBetween:15` обеспечило при динамическом изменении количества видимых слайдов, распределить их равномерно и организовать между ними отступ в `15px`.

Пример кода для 4 слайдов:

```js
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    swiperSlides: [
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
    ],
    swiperOption: {
      initialSlide: 0,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 15,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    swiper() {
      return this.$refs.mySwiper.swiper;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // current swiper instance
  },
  methods: {
    callback() {
      //read the API docs to see which slider events are available
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  /*width: 100px;*/
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}

.box-slider {
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-awesome-swiper@3.1.3/dist/vue-awesome-swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>

    <div class="box-slider">
      <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper" @someSwiperEvent="callback">
        <!-- slides -->
        <swiper-slide v-for="(slide, index) in swiperSlides" :key="index">
          <div class="square">
            img
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
      </swiper>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Пример кода для 6 слайдов:

```js
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    swiperSlides: [
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
      "grey",
    ],
    swiperOption: {
      initialSlide: 0,
      slidesPerView: 6,
      spaceBetween: 15,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
      }
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    swiper() {
      return this.$refs.mySwiper.swiper;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // current swiper instance
  },
  methods: {
    callback() {
      //read the API docs to see which slider events are available
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.square {
  height: 100px;
  /*width: 100px;*/
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}

.box-slider {
  width: 600px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-awesome-swiper@3.1.3/dist/vue-awesome-swiper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <div  id="app" class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>

    <div class="box-slider">
      <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper" @someSwiperEvent="callback">
        <!-- slides -->
        <swiper-slide v-for="(slide, index) in swiperSlides" :key="index">
          <div class="square">
            img
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>
      </swiper>
    </div>

  </div>
```